# Nested Do While inner loop runs only on first iteration of outer loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do a multiple condition search. If two parameters are equal to another two parameters in another worksheet, then do something.

The inner `Do While` runs once.

```
Sub main()

Dim mat As String
Dim sp As String

Dim colArt As Integer
colArt = 8

Dim colMat As Integer
colMat = 2

Sheets("Art.1 (2)").Activate
Dim i As Integer
i = 5

Dim j As Integer
j = 2 'Row
Do While i < 12
    If (Cells(i, colArt) <> "") Then

        Dim tempMat As String
        tempMat = Cells(i, colArt)

        Dim tempSp As Integer
        tempSp = Cells(i, colArt - 1)

        Do While j < 16
            If (Worksheets("Mat").Cells(j, colMat) <> "") Then

                Dim tempMatMat As String
                tempMatMat = Worksheets("Mat").Cells(j, colMat)

                If (StrComp(tempMat, tempMatMat, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
                    MsgBox (tempMatMat)
                End If

            End If
        j = j + 1
        Loop

    End If
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `j` needs resetting to `0` after/before the inner loop else the 2nd time round its value does not satisfy the `while` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Federico, you need to reset `j` each time you loop in the outer loop:

```
Do While i < 12
    j = 2
    If (Cells(i, colArt) <> "") Then
        Dim tempMat As String
        tempMat = Cells(i, colArt)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Little left over, didnt see that ahah

Comment: You're welcome.  Easy thing to overlook.  Whenever an do-while loop only works **once** this is a thing to look out for.